# directive post link function - focus on element once it's visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following directive to allow focusing on an element:

```
angular.module('app').directive('focusOn', ['$timeout', function ($timeout){

    return {
        scope: {
            focusOn: '=focusOn'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.$watch('focusOn', function (shouldFocus) {
                if (shouldFocus) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $element[0].focus();
                        $scope.focusOn = false;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };

}]);
```

I am using this directive as an attribute on a `textarea` with `focusOn="isFirst"`, which is initialized in the controller to `true`. The problem is that when focusOn is set to true (and the if inside the watch is executed), the element is not yet visible in the DOM, and thus the focus does not work. I added the $timeout in an attempt to solve this, but it did not help. How can I ensure that `.focus()` is called only once the element is visible (and focusable)?

Comment: provide demo that replicates this

Comment: element should be accessible there without a timeout, you may want to provide us more context. Use the inline code snippet editor in the SO itself to showcase your issue perhaps?

Comment: have you tried adding terminal flag, with value true ?

Comment: @PSL element is available here, but it is not visible yet (checking jquey's :visible returns false)

Comment: @user3836205 then you have more directives like ng-show/ng-hide on the element, without showing us the full context it would be difficult for anyone to guess i believe.